# Why is my image too bright when I take a 5 second exposure outdoors?

Tags: exposure, shutter-speed, overexposure, shutter-priority

I've never had this problem with my Canon Rebel T6i, but when I am on the Tv setting and changing it to let's say 5 seconds, when I try to take a picture outside it is way too light. When I did this before it was NOT too light. I tried changing my ISO but that didn't help at all. It stayed the same.

Is there something wrong with my camera, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are doing something wrong. You need to learn about the exposure triangle, and how aperture, shutter speed and ISO setting all combine to set the exposure. Also, "taking a picture outside" tells us nothing about the light level of the scene. Was it at noon? At midnight? Don't answer that - you get the idea.

Comment: As I was trying to take a picture outside during DAY LIGHT my camera was all white as in "too bright" and couldnt see nothing on my tv mode setting. Ive tried changing the settings but it didn't really change much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An outdoor shot at 5s *should* be massively overexposed. Taking the "Sunny 16" rule - at f/16 on a sunny day, your exposure should be 1 / (ISO) seconds - assuming you're at ISO 100, your correct exposure at f/16 will be 1/100s, or if your lens can stop down to f/22, 1/50s.

However, you're approximately 8 stops over that (5 / (1/50) = 250, log<sub>2</sub> 250 ~ 8), so you're massively overexposed. Even allowing for a cloudy day, you're not going to get a good exposure outdoors at 5s unless you've got a big neutral density filter on. Whatever you thought was happening before wasn't happening.

Comment: Ok good then its not a problem I guess. But should I be able to change my f/(number) bc I can only change the shutter speed and iso number and when I press one of the zoom buttons on my camera the f/(number) comes up but won't let me change it. Sorry if this does not make sense to you. Thanks for you help!!

Comment: @anjphoto You can't change the aperture because you're in shutter priority mode ("Tv"). If you want to set both the shutter speed and the aperture, you should be using Manual mode ("M").

Comment: You're in shutter priority (Tv) mode - therefore you're explicitly saying you want the camera to set the aperture. If you want control over aperture as well, then go into manual mode... however, without wanting to seem harsh, it doesn't sound like you're ready for that yet - in particular, there are no "zoom buttons" on your camera. Perhaps time to step back to program mode and learn a little more about your camera?

Comment: That's all I wanted to know if I could change aperture in tv mode setting prior to my question. Now I know. Thanks!